# How to create a regular setting aside only a list of values for 3 element

Tags: xml, groovy

I have xml that I get from the link, the problem is that I need a regular expression that will leave only a list of versions.

```
def listOfVersion = uc.getInputStream().text

regex = /[7]{1}\.[0-9]{1,}\..*/
println listOfVersion.findAll{it=~regex}.takeRight(3).reverse()
```

the output is an empty list, this is not true

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
  <group>my.app</group>
  <artifact>server</artifact>
  <versioning>
    <latest>1.0.1</latest>
    <release>1.0.0</release>
    <versions>
      <version>1.0.0.2</version>
      <version>1.0.0.1</version>
      <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>2232323336</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

conclusion

```
[]
```

you need to get a list of versions both release and just versions

Comment: I think, a regular expression ist not the best Kind of solution Here. There are libraries for reading XML content.

Comment: Groovy even has built in support for parsing xml

Comment: and then how do I get a list of versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Donat pointed in the comments, regex is probably not the best solution here. I would go with XML parsing using [XmlSlurper](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/xml/XmlSlurper.html). It also allows you to directly read data from your URL. As an example, try this:

```
def xml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
  <group>my.app</group>
  <artifact>server</artifact>
  <versioning>
    <latest>1.0.1</latest>
    <release>1.0.0</release>
    <versions>
      <version>1.0.0.2</version>
      <version>1.0.0.1</version>
      <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>2232323336</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
"""

def parsed = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
def versions = parsed.versioning.versions.version.collect { it.text() }
println "versions: $versions"
```

Comment: thank you, only I get xml by the link from the resource

Comment: i use that:

def url = new URL("https://my site/blaballslsl")
URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();

Comment: @Laplas not sure I understand, but you can definitely use "parse" method instead of "parseText" that I mentioned in the answer. Something like that: "def parsed = new XmlSlurper().parse(your_URL_as_a_plain_string)"